# AbiWord document's borders keeps flashing

Tags: abiword

I downloaded AbiWord 3.0.1. 
When I begin writing or reading a document, the borders of the document starts flashing ceaselessly. 
I've tried uninstalling AbiWord and installing it again, with no success.
What should I do in order to fix this problem?

Help much appreciated. 
Thank you.

Comment: Which Ubuntu and DE you're using?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04.1. Unity DE.

Comment: which border it is?

Comment: What do you mean by which?

Comment: Is it bottom border or all 4?

Comment: The first 3 without the bottom border

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44683/discussion-between-anwar-and-n-even).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After my testing and discussion with the OP in chat, it reveals that the problem is actually a theme related bug. There are different reports of this bug and a workaround is changing the default theme. Here is one of the [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/abiword/+bug/1019621).

But it needed test to check which themes work. Some theme seem to not working and some does work. After further test, I curated this list of themes that fix the issue.

- Arc Theme
- Arc Flatabulous Theme
- Ceti 2 theme
- Vertext theme
- Menda and Menda Dark theme
- Paper theme
- Adwaita theme

You can find these themes by searching. Here is a link of Noobslab PPA, who has some good collection of themes

- [Noobslab Themes Collection](https://launchpad.net/~noobslab/+archive/ubuntu/themes)

To install themes from the PPA. first add it using this two commands

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/themes
sudo apt-get update
```

Then install it by

```
sudo apt-get install <theme-name-here>
```

Comment: Did not solve for me... :/